# Launch Cortana from C# Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, speech-recognition, cortana

I'm working on an app where i need to be able to open cortana on an event and have it listen for a users commands. Are there any API's that make this possible?

Curently i have

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("bing://home"));
```

However, this does not cause it to listen

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no programmatic way to launch Cortana, but depending on your needs you can do the speech dictation directly within your app, either based on a set of command grammars or just using free-form dictation.

- For Windows Runtime apps, use [`Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechrecognition.aspx)
- For Silverlight apps, use [`Windows.Phone.Speech.Recognition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.speech.recognition.aspx)